# Cordova chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create not work

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, tcpserver

I try to use chrome tcpServer but it dose not work, no log displayed in console and no errors:

```
    chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create({}, function(info){
      console.log('info', info);
      chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen(info.socketId, '127.0.0.1', 80, null,
        function(result){
          console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

Then I tried to use `chrome.system.network.getInterfaces` but I have this error : `Could not get network interfaces`

Comment: Is your getInterfaces call invoked on the same machine (same script, app, etc)?  Meaning , is 127.0.0.1 relevant?